# How to make a Google Drive files GET request using partial response that includes exportLinks / "text/plain"?

Tags: google-drive-api

Within the OAuth 2.0 Playground, I can make this request, and it is valid:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?fields=items(id,exportLinks)
```

However, what I want to capture is just one of the export links: "text/plain". But if I request that specific field:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?fields=items(exportLinks/text/plain)
```

I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "invalidParameter",
     "message": "Invalid field selection plain",
     "locationType": "parameter",
     "location": "fields"
    }
  ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Invalid field selection plain"
  }
}
```

How do I specify that a partial should include "exportLinks" / "text/plain"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't request a specific exportLink type. You need to request them all "items(exportLinks)" and then look for the "text/plain" property of the returned exportLinks object ("var url = exportLinks['text/plain']")